# Table Rendering Incorrectly

Tags: html, html-table

I have a table in HTML. I am new to creating web pages so I am doing simple basic HTML I'm not using style ( tho I should ) nor CSS sheets.  I'm not using them cause I'm trying to understand basic html then will learn how to bring advanced topics.  This table will render like I want in Chrome.  In FireFox the structure is fine but colors are wrong. In IE8 the text in the merged cells rows 1 and 2 don't render and none of the text in IE8 is centered.

I'm looking but how do I determine which properties ( and I"m trying to use nothing special ) aren't being used in a particular browser?  Here is my table html

```
     <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">  
 <html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"  
 xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">  
 <!-- -->  
 <HEAD>  
 <title>Atmel CSO < DEPTNAMEHERE> Dashboard</title>  

 </HEAD>  
 <!-- -->  
 <BODY leftmargin="22" link="#000000" alink="#000000" bgcolor="white" vlink="#000000" text="#000000">  
 <center>  
 <table border="1" width="">  
 <tr> <!-- Row 1 -->  
 <td width="20" align="" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(255,255,255)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">&nbsp;</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="22" rowspan="2" bgcolor="rgb(255,255,255)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(255,0,0)">Dry Etch Tool Status as of 10/18/2010 6:10:50 AM</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(255,255,255)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">&nbsp;</font></td>  
 </tr>  
 <tr> <!-- Row 2 -->  
 <td width="20" align="" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(255,255,255)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">&nbsp;</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(255,255,255)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">&nbsp;</font></td>  
 </tr>  
 <tr> <!-- Row 3 -->  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,0,255)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(255,255,255)">WJ</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="2" rowspan="1" bgcolor="rgb(0,0,255)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(255,255,255)">Hoods</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="6" rowspan="1" bgcolor="rgb(0,0,255)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(255,255,255)">Metals</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="4" rowspan="1" bgcolor="rgb(0,0,255)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(255,255,255)">WCVD</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="3" rowspan="1" bgcolor="rgb(0,0,255)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(255,255,255)">HDP</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="3" rowspan="1" bgcolor="rgb(0,0,255)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(255,255,255)">AST</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,0,255)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(255,255,255)">NOV'L</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="4" rowspan="1" bgcolor="rgb(0,0,255)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(255,255,255)">SACVD</font></td>  

 </tr>  
 <tr> <!-- Row 4 -->  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)"><b>C015</b></font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="2" rowspan="1" bgcolor="rgb(255,255,255)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)"><b>H725</b></font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="6" rowspan="1" bgcolor="rgb(255,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)"><b>S015</b></font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="4" rowspan="1" bgcolor="rgb(255,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)"><b>PX055</b></font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="3" rowspan="1" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)"><b>HDP015</b></font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="3" rowspan="1" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)"><b>R015</b></font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)"><b>P045</b></font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="4" rowspan="1" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)"><b>SA015</b></font></td>  

 </tr>  
 <tr> <!-- Row 5 -->  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,204,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)"><b>C025</b></font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,204,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">A</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">B</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">1</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">2</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">3</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">4</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(255,255,255)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">&nbsp;</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(255,255,255)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">&nbsp;</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">A</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">B</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">C</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">D</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">A</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">B</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">C</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(255,255,255)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">&nbsp;</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(255,255,255)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">&nbsp;</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(255,255,255)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">&nbsp;</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,204,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)"><b>P055</b></font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">A</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">B</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">C</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">D</font></td>  
 </tr>  
 <tr> <!-- Row 6 -->  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,204,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)"><b>C035</b></font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="2" rowspan="1" bgcolor="rgb(255,255,255)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)"><b>H374</b></font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="6" rowspan="1" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)"><b>S025</b></font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="4" rowspan="1" bgcolor="rgb(255,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)"><b>PX065</b></font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="3" rowspan="1" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)"><b>HDP025</b></font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="3" rowspan="1" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)"><b>R025</b></font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,204,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)"><b>P065</b></font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="4" rowspan="1" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)"><b>SA025</b></font></td>  

 </tr>  
 <tr> <!-- Row 7 -->  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)"><b>C045</b></font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,204,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">B</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">C</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">1</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">2</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">3</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">4</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(255,255,255)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">&nbsp;</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(255,255,255)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">&nbsp;</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">A</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">B</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(255,0,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">C</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">D</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">A</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">B</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">C</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(255,255,255)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">&nbsp;</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(255,255,255)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">&nbsp;</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(255,255,255)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">&nbsp;</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="left" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(153,51,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)"><b> </b></font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">A</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">B</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">C</font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)">D</font></td>  
 </tr>  
 <tr> <!-- Row 8 -->  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)"><b>C055</b></font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="2" rowspan="1" bgcolor="rgb(153,51,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)"><b> </b></font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="6" rowspan="1" bgcolor="rgb(255,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)"><b>S035</b></font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="4" rowspan="1" bgcolor="rgb(255,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)"><b>PX075</b></font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="3" rowspan="1" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)"><b>HDP035</b></font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="3" rowspan="1" bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)"><b>R035</b></font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="" rowspan="" bgcolor="rgb(255,153,0)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)"><b>P034</b></font></td>  
 <td width="20" align="center" colspan="4" rowspan="1" bgcolor="rgb(255,255,255)"><font name="courier" size="" color="rgb(0,0,0)"><b>SA035</b></font></td>  

 </tr>  
 </table  
 </center>  
 </BODY>  
 <!-- -->  
 </html>
```

Comment: please avoid inline styles from now on. that is a good start. the font and center tags have been deprecated long ago

Comment: http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfhtml/

Answer (score 0):

I believe the rgb attribute is HTML5 which is not supported by IE prior to IE9.

Comment: Not quite correct, this was definitely supposed to be possible in HTML 4 ... not that it necessarily works in all browsers :)

Comment: “HTML5 is not supported by IE prior to IE9” is just not true. HTML5 is more than you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

An evil answer, but firefox just doesn't appear to support using "rgb(x,y,z)" in that context, even though the HTML specification says that it should.  It seems to try to parse out a hex colour value (ie. #123456), resulting in seemingly random colours being presented.  The "bgcolor" attribute is deprecated, even in HTML 4, so I'd recommend against its usage if avoidable.

If you want firefox compatibility, you'll want to either move the background colour definition into a "style" attribute, using CSSesque syntax to specify it, or switch to standard hex format.

- `<td style="background-color: rgb(255,103,0);">`
- `<td bgcolor="#ff6700">`